# dotnet CLI Как указать версию .Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, консоль, dotnet-cli

Как можно указать версию .Net Core через cli. 
На компе стоят DotNet core v. 2.0, 2.1, 2.2.
 По умолчанию создаётся версия 2.2.
 А, я к примеру хочу командой `dotnet new mvc -n BlaBla` установить версию 2.0 или 2.1. Как это можно сделать. Не как не могу найти команду в интернете.

Comment: [dotnet new](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-new?tabs=netcore21). В самом конце пример команды: `dotnet new globaljson --sdk-version 2.0.0`.

Comment: @Alexander Отлично работает! Спасибо!